# how to remove "Powered by Searchanise" from the search bar

Tags: magento-1.9, search, delete, home-page

I am building the magento ecommerce website named "bookslab.in". I want to remove the "Powered by Searchanise" from the search bar of my magento site. I had attached the screenshot of which section i have to remove & how much part i have to remove. I had installed an Searchanise extension. Any help will be appreciated. Someone suggested my to edit in module, but how  to edit this module. Any one know please answer this if anyone did not got i will explain them again. While accessing the Putty to connect with SSH getting "Connection Timout" error.

[image]

Comment: This is an additional module / service. You should either disable it (modules output / app/etc/modules) or configure / modify it. It probably came with your theme. You should contact them for customizations. Their methods are aggressive in my opinion. They made me a subscriber to their service by fetching my email address from my admin account as I installed the theme for my customer. This isn't a common magento thing.

Comment: i had navigated  to my module but hoe to disabled it

Comment: how to update in module file of Searchanise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

1. **Brute find and remove**

   SSH to magento root folder and search for 'Searchanise':

   ```
   find ./app ./skin ./lib ./js -type f -exec grep -iHn --color=always 'Powered by.*Searchanise' {} \;
   ```

   if found edit the file and remove it.
2. **Display:none for html element**

   Use Chrome inspector or Firefox devtools to find class name or ID of an element that contains 'Powered by Searchanise':
   [image]
   once found add this CSS rules to your styles.css file:

   ```
   .classname{display:none;}
   ```

Comment: Okzz i will check & get back to you

Comment: Not able to search a Searchanise, what are the steps to edit by following the first method you suggest "Brute....

Comment: Any reply or answer to this question stacky's

Comment: i am not sure I understand you - you couldn't run find command?

Comment: Can u tell me how to run file command

Comment: connect to server via ssh (google how to use it),  change directory to your magento root folder, where index.php is (for example cd /var/www/). copy paste the command in the answer.

Comment: Okzz i will check n let u know about this

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Konstantin Gerasimov. Now i am using Putty to connect with SSH, but it throws Connection Refused error.

Comment: Salman make sure your hosting enables SSH for your account and your IP is whitelisted. just ping your hosting support saying you can't connect via SSH

Comment: Okzz i will do that

Answer (score 0):

You are able to remove powered by text using jQuery. Following is one of the method is to remove text.

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    setInterval(function(){
        jQuery('.snize-ac-results a').each(function() {
            if (jQuery(this).text() == 'Powered by Searchanise')
                jQuery(this).text('');
        });
    }, 3000);
});
</script>`

This code will not work if they will change class name as '.snize-ac-results'. This is temporary/quick solution now.